# prevent div resizing because of inner text

Tags: css, html

Here is my code:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <img ...>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
      <p style="text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;">HERE MAY BE SONE VERY LONG TEST!!!</p>
    </td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I want the width of my div as wide as my image, but since I don't know how wide my image is, I can't specify a width for the p to keep it in bounds.

I am looking for an html(+css) only solution, if there is any. I know how I could accomplish this in js, but that gets messy since the image size is changed over time.

Is there a way to do this in pure html/css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply set the width of the table to be very small:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e93pz/2/)**

```
table
{
    width: 1px;
}
```